# What is the purpose of "@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")"?

Tags: android

I have found following code on net. I am confused about the first line. What is the purpose of this line ?

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void showAlert(String title,String msg,final Class cls)
{
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);
    alertDialog.setMessage(msg);
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent samepage = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                    cls);
            startActivity(samepage);

        }
    });
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an unchecked generics conversion / casting in the code inside of the method.

So by indicating a `@SuppressWarnings` annotation, you don't get a warning from the IDE or compilation, as you are telling the compiler that you are aware and you don't get warnings.